# Use what type of images in android app?

Tags: android, image, png

I am working on tutorial app and I have more than 15 images in my app. When I use **.png** format images all images take too much size. And I check the difference in **.jpg** and **.png**. If I take same image with dimensions 320*480 **.jpg** image take 18 kb but **.png** take 60 kb size. So what type of images do I have to use? And if **.png** is preferable then how to decrease size of each image without affecting resolution?

Comment: .png images are heavy. Unless you want transparency, its better to use jpegs.

Comment: @sayed.jali It's not just about transparency, it's about image quality too. Never use jpegs for icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what type of images do I have to use?

For any picture that is part of your user interface (i.e icons, logos, placeholders), use PNG. It's not even about transparency, it's about pixel perfect design.

> And if .png preferable than how to decrease size of each image without affecting resolution?

There are many PNG compressors out there. Here are a couple of easy web-based ones.

- http://pngcrush.com/
- https://tinypng.com/

You can also get PNGcrush as a standalone executable which lets you tweak compression options, and integrate it into your build system.

Related Info: [Why PNGs are bigger than they should be](http://webcharts.stackunderflow.com/comic/17)

Comment: one more little question I want to use one image as background that cover whole screen and i want its fit on all screen sizes. what dimension image i have to take?

Comment: @JohnR *it depends*, both on the target platforms, and on the image. [Screen Sizes and Densities](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) charts will help you target devices, [Screen Support docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) should help you pick resolutions. If your image is detailed, you'll want high res imagery. If your image is blurred or a gradient, or made of simple shapes, you could get away with 1:2 pixel ratio on high resolution screens. Be aware that you can specify *multiple images* for different *sizes and densities*.